# rsync not detecting changed file with option --append-verify

Tags: linux, files, rsync, synchronization, checksum

I have invoked `rsync` with the options `--checksum` and `--append-verify`.

My understanding of the   processing for this combination of options has been that the application would behave as in the following procedure:

- If a file exists only on the source, transfer it by copying it to the target location in place.
- If it exists on both the source and target, incrementally verify the checksum on both sides.
- At any point at which the checksum computations diverge, indicating mismatched content, or any point at which one file ends before the other, update the remaining content of the target, from the source.

  *Updating the remaining content in this sense may entail truncating, overwriting, and appending the target.*

  Such behavior would be in contrast to that caused by `--append`, which only causes the target file to be appended, if it is shorter than the source.

After crunching countless data sets of over the past years with the combination of options `--checksum`, `--append-verify`, and `--verbose` (and usually `--recurse`, where appropriate), as an intended means to ensure the sameness of two  file trees, I have now observed that the behavior of `rsync` using such a parameter combination is not what I expected.

Strangely, even though `rsync` crunches away, on both sides of the wire, to compute the checksum of every file that exists on both, it seems simply to  ignore any mismatch as long as the lengths of both file are the same.

**What is the actual behavior and purpose of the option `--append-verify`, with and without `--checksum`, and how may I achieve the behavior I have identified as my intention?**

**Finally, if I may raise a more subjective matter without strong objection, am I alone in considering the actual behavior I have described as not only unexpected, but also dangerous?***

Answer (score 0):

In short:

1. `--checksum` is a way, how `rsync` determines if 2 files are identical
2. `--append` and `--append-verify` are ONLY useful if the source file is larger than the destination file. The difference is only the checksum-calculation after the transfer is done (has nothing to do with the above option). The former calculates the checksum over the whole file, the latter only over the appended part. If you use `--append` with a file that has changed the content of the "old" part, you'll get an error as far as i can remember.

I haven't found a sensible use-case with either append nowadays, the only scenario would be ever growing logfiles. With logfile-rotation this is nonsense anyways.

Comment: I am not able actually to resolve any particular and clear execution flow based on the explanations, due to the vagueness of the language. For example, mention is made of calculating check sums, but not of when this calculation is made or what is done with the result to determine the next step.

Comment: The reason is you can't. either transfer complete file or just append (no changes in the "old" fileparts). The manpage is clear on that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following the meaning of your response. "You can't" do what? My comment was about resolving execution flow. Is that what "you can't" do?

Comment: You can't "achieve the behavior I have identified as my intention" with rsync. append-verify only works on the growing part of a file. If a file has changes at the "beginning", you have to transfer the whole file. If `rsync` doesn't do what you expected it MIGHT be that your expection is the problem. `rsync` is well documented and the append-options only work for the additional parts of a file.